# Change inner html every x seconds

Tags: javascript, html

how to change itens in a table with javascript, every 15 seconds using uinnerHTML:

```
document.getElementById("iten1").innerHTML = "Bla Bla Bla";
```

Comment: Please provide some more context.

Comment: So, im making a website that show prices of products, and i want to refresh the table with new itens every 15 seconds, how can i do that?

Comment: What text are you refreshing it with?

Comment: Your question is not descriptive enough, but I'm sure `setInterval()` is what you're looking for

Comment: <ul>
                <li id="item 1" class="impar">Item 1 description</li>
</ul>

Comment: ```setInterval(() => { //your codes here}, 15000); ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a recursive timeout loop.

```
function timeout() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    // Do Something Here
    // Then recall the parent function to
    // create a recursive loop.
    timeout();
  }, 1000);
}
```

If you're new to setTimeout() MDN has a pretty straightforward guide you can play around with. : [setTimeout <sup><sub>*MDN*</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: Thats what i was looking for, ty so much! *-* Seriously you helped me so much!!!!

Comment: @TheXandD That's until you'll realize that setTimeout is not accurate. You cannot represent seconds or even milliseconds accurately using setTimeout `1000` or `15000` alone. Google and SO is full of such answers, all it takes is a little more research.